# Exporting Highcharts to png in java - encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in my java application to generate png with chart. In my processing I generate string that contains options for chart like this:

```
{
    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
        width: 1040,
        height: 400,
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '뾿뾿 89 %'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['四月', '五月', '六月', '七月', '八月', '九月']
    ...
```

To export it to png I am using this [class](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export/blob/master/src/org/one2team/highcharts/server/export/HighchartsExporter.java).
Recently I tried using Chinese language, as you can see in code above. Code entering the exporter is encoded in utf-8, but when I get my picture generated Chinese characters turn into question marks. I can't find any way to set encoding in this exporter.

Comment: Just created [this export](http://i.imgur.com/1fyNNYA.png) using [this code](http://pastebin.com/YVC90cxn). Had no problems. I'd suspect there to still be some encoding problem.

Comment: Well that is strange, I had similar java code to yours, but anyway: I copied your code and I got this http://i.imgur.com/2dhqRBQ.png

Comment: What editor are you using? I used Eclipse set to UTF-8 for both the project and my own code.

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA and my encodings are set like this http://imgur.com/Cud5laV

Comment: Have your tried to check your fonts on server? Maybe some of them not cover chinese characters?

Comment: Yes, it seems that problem was all along with my font, I was using the one prepared (and licensed) for web browser usage, not pdf